# Deleting multiple items using checkboxes in PHP using ajax or jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to delete multiple items in the database table using checkbox. I did this with PHP, but now I want to do it with javascript so it will not refresh the page. How can I amend my code below so it will delete multiple items without refreshing page?

**HTML**

```
<div id="msg"></div>
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" id='remove[]-<?php echo $item_id;?>' name="remove[]" value="<?php echo $item_id; ?>" />
  <button class="btn btn-danger" id="del_btn" type="submit" name="delete" 
      onclick='return del(<?php echo $item_id;?>)'><b>DELETE</b></button>
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 function del(item_id){
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"delete_form.php",
        data: { 
            id: item_id, 
            name: $('#remove[]-'+item_id).val() 
        },
        cache:false,
        success: function(html){
            $('#msg').html(html);
         }
        });
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
     return false;
}
```

**PHP**

```
foreach ((array) $_POST['remove'] as $remove_id) {
    $delete_item = "delete from products where item_id='$remove_id'";
    $run_delete = mysqli_query($con, $delete_item);
    if ($run_delete){
        echo "<h3> was deleted successfully</h3>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Just loop through all the ticked boxes when you hit the onclick, then sent it to the PHP file

Answer (score 0):

Try to loop in your js to get an array of ids.

```
 var array = [];
   $.each($(inputclass),function(a){
   if($(this).is(':checked')===true){
     array.push($(this).val());
    }
  }
```

Then in the parameter of the ajax call, send it.

In php recive it and loop the values making the delete.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't quite make sense as you are passing only one item in your JavaScript, but looping and deleting multiple items in your PHP.

If you have a form like

```
<form>
    <!-- id is useless IMO -->
    <input type="checkbox" name="remove[]" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="remove[]" value="2" />
    <!-- etc -->
    <!-- change type to button to prevent the form from submitting -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="del_btn"><b>DELETE</b></button>
</form>
```

[Attach an onclick event handler](https://api.jquery.com/click/) to your button. Simply [serialize your form](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to get the "checked" checkboxes.

```
$('#del_btn').click(function () {
    $.post("delete_form.php", $(this).closest('form').serialize(), function (html) {
        $('#msg').html(html);
    });
});
```

In your PHP, instead of looping, use one query using [IN](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm) operator

```
$ids = $_POST['remove'];
$in = implode(', ', $ids); // [1, 2, 3] becomes '1, 2, 3'
$sql = "DELETE FROM products WHERE item_id IN ($in)";

if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    echo "<h3> was deleted successfully</h3>";
} else {
    echo "<h3> something went wrong</h3>";
}
```

Aside: your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, so you should probably validate the data received before running your SQL.

Comment: Thank for your response. Your code works, but it seems not to be stable. Sometimes if I click the Delete button the form disappears without deleting anything, sometimes it will delete the item and echo deleted. Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: @Oponjous You copied the code **exactly** as shown above (nothing more, nothing less) ? Open your browser's console log and see if any errors show up after you click on the button. Turn on [PHP error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5438125/1022914) at the top of your PHP file as well. Ensure your jQuery is [correctly placed](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/) in the document.